# Class Library (Package) project with error when installing SpecFlow.NUnit

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have just created a  Class Library (Package) project. I have never used this template before. When I install SpecFlow.NUnit, my References folder is displayed "References (Errors - see error list)". My SpecFlow.NUnit has that warning sign. Maybe I shouldn't use this type of project but I would like to understand why. Thanks.

Update: I've tried installing SpecFlow.xUnit in a second project too without success. I've installed them through Nuget.

Comment: How did you install SpecFlow?

Comment: I updated the question. I made the installations through Nuget

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions, should not be any problem. And use a Test project, that is the easiest way to get started.

[Specflow documentation](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Setup-SpecFlow-Projects/)

Comment: If I create a project through the template "Class Library" (without package)  I can install it ok. I just wanted to know why it doesn't work with Package. Thanks.

Comment: have you installed the ide integration? http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Install-IDE-Integration/